# Eloquent ORM: getting "id" instead of "user_id" when creating new user

Tags: orm, laravel, eloquent

I have a table

```
Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('user_id');
        $table->string('user_login')->unique();
        $table->string('user_password');
        $table->string('user_email');
        $table->string('user_type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Then I create a user

```
$data = Input::all();

    $user = new User;
    $user->user_login    = $data['user_login'];
    $user->user_email    = $data['user_email'];
    $user->user_type     = $data['user_type'];
    $user->user_password = Hash::make($data['user_password']);

    $user->save();

    return Response::json($user);
```

And then I have

```
{"user_login":"User5","user_email":"user@mail.ru","user_type":"1","user_password":"$2y$10$lqnruQT2EIfqw3m9fi8S8OskmmuQ4mfVuvw0Dbn5fb5.yuw8E7WAa","updated_at":"2014-05-08 11:03:01","created_at":"2014-05-08 11:03:01","id":6}
```

How can I get "user_id" instead of "id" in my response using Laravel way, without constructions like $user->user_id = $user->id?

Or is it just the way ORM works, and it can't be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify primary key on your `User` model:

```
class User extends \Eloquent {

  protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

  ...

}
```